# Losing texture definition in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, fragment-shader

I am trying to draw a reference grid using fragment shader, and I found that the texture loses its definition when zooming out as you can see here. Anybody knows why? It looks fine when zoom in.

grid texture on a quad when out
[image]

grid texture with no zoom
[image]

And here is the code:

```
#version 330 core
uniform int multiplicationFactor;
uniform lowp float threshold;
uniform vec4 gridColor;

in vec2 vUV;

void main() {
    // multiplicationFactor scales the number of stripes
    vec2 t = vUV * multiplicationFactor;

    // the threshold constant defines the with of the lines
    if (abs(t.x - round(t.x)) <= threshold  || abs(t.y - round(t.y)) < threshold )
        gl_FragColor = gridColor;    
    else
        discard;
}
```

Comment: Looks a precision problem. Does 't = uUV;' and comparing against '(threshold / multiplicationFactor)' make any difference?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant but if you were concerned about the low precision on threshold value, I am sure that's not a problem. I have tested with high to low precision and see that there is imperceptible change in the texture!

Comment: Not quite, but I think Rabbid76 has the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the distance to the line in relation to the size of the viewport.

Add a uniform variable of type `vec2 resolution` which contains the width and height of the viewport and the variable `threshold`hast to contain the thickness of the line in pixel (e.g. 1.0):

```c
#version 330 core

uniform int        multiplicationFactor;
uniform lowp float threshold;   // line width in pixel
uniform vec4       gridColor;
uniform vec2       resolution;  // width and height of the viewport

in vec2 vUV;

void main()
{
    float m   = float(multiplicationFactor);
    vec2 t    = vUV * m;
    vec2 dist = abs(t - round(t)) / m; 
    vec2 th   = threshold / resolution;

    if (dist.x > th.x  && dist.y > th.y)
        discard;

    gl_FragColor = gridColor;    
}
```

Comment: It was not quite what I expected from your original code (the solid line becomes dashed line). When I change the line : vec2 dist = abs(t - round(t)) / m;  to vec2 dist = abs(t - round(t)) / resolution; it becomes solid again! and the quality of texture definitely improves. I'll just note this down as scaling distance limitation of OpenGL graphics pipeline. I can't vote for your answer because it's my first day here but thanks by all means +1